# Darktable no longer starts

Tags: 15.10, darktable

When I try to start [Darktable](http://www.darktable.org/) 1.6.8 on Ubuntu Studio 15.10, I see an hourglass cursor for about a minute. Then, nothing happens. Same thing when I uninstall and reinstall Darktable.

~/.config/darktable contains a file library.db.lock.

Yesterday all my troubles seem so far away.

Answer (score 0):

Delete ~/.config/darktable/library.db.lock with the rm command.